# Basic binary Tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, tree

I wrote a basic binary tree in JS. Can anyone give me some feedback about my code?

I just want to know if this is the right approach, and how I can improve the tree. I am new to JavaScript and data structures.

```
function bst() {
    this.root = null;
}

bst.prototype.insert = function( obj ){

    if ( this.root == null ){
        this.root = new node(obj);
    }
    else if (this.root.value > obj){
         if (this.root.left != null ){
            this.root.left.insert( obj );
        }
        else {
            this.root.left = new node(obj);
        }
    } 
    else if (this.root.value < obj){
        if (this.root.right != null ){
            this.root.right.insert( obj );
        }
        else {
            this.root.right = new node(obj);
        }
    }
}

    function node( obj ){

   this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.value = obj;

    }

node.prototype.insert = function( obj ){

if (this.value > obj){

    if (this.left != null){
        this.left.insert( obj )
    }
    else{
        this.left = new node(obj);
    }
}

else if (this.value < obj){

    if (this.right != null){
        this.right.insert( obj )
    }
    else{
        this.right = new node(obj);
    }
}
//elase duplicated key value
else{
    console.log("duplicated bst key")
}

}

var bst = new bst();
bst.insert(25);
bst.insert(75);
bst.insert(12);
bst.insert(37);
bst.insert(87);
bst.insert(63);

console.log(bst.root.value);
console.log(bst.root.left.value);
console.log(bst.root.right.value);
console.log(bst.root.right.left.value);
console.log(bst.root.right.right.value);
console.log(bst.root.right.left.right.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see two obvious points:

- Constructor names are usually capitalized, to indicate that they should be invoked with `new`
- You've got some code duplication between `bst::insert` and `node::insert`. This even leads to the bug that you don't recognise/handle duplicate values in the root node.

So, I'd suggest:

```
function Bst() {
    this.root = null;
}
Bst.prototype.insert = function(obj) {
    if (this.root == null) {
        this.root = new Node(obj);
    } else {
        this.root.insert(obj);
    }
};
```

> I am new to data structures.

[Binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) are a wide field :-) First, I'm missing some other basic operations like *searching*, *traversing*, and *deleting*. If you have mastered these, you can go on with optimizing your tree, e.g. making it a balanced one.